# How to set Delphi bookmarks on Vista 64-bit

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-2007, bookmarks

In Delphi (2007) I'm used to setting a bookmark with CTRL-SHIFT-0,1,2 etc.

Since I've upgraded to Vista x64 the above no longer works. I can still set a bookmark with CTRL-K-0,1,2 etc but I'm habituated to the traditional way (plus it's quicker).

Does anyone know why it's not working for me?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. Some more investigation showed that it is caused by a change in Vista.

Input method editor keyboard shortcut (CTRL+SHIFT+0) switches the input language in Vista. The following link shows how to disable this shortcut and thereby make it available to other applications (including Delphi) again: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967893.

Answer (score 2):

I am running on Windows 2008 Server 64-Bit (which is based on Vista) and I use CTRL+SHIFT+1 to set book marks and it works fine.  At home I have Vista 32-Bit and that works fine too.

You might check to make sure your OEM didn't install some crazy keyboard hook on that or something.  I've had that happen before where some key combinations were remapped by a background program and it prevented them from working in Delphi.

Programmers use a lot more key combinations then most "normal" users.

Answer (score 2):

Verify that you don't have system wide hot keys that conflict with those. I had the same problem with Trillian hijacking some Delphi shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, Vista is using that key combination.

If you don't want to disable it, Ctrl+K CTRL+0 is the old school method to set bookmark 0.